# OpenCV blend mode implementation: Why do seemingly equivalent operations have different results?

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, pointers, image-processing

I have a blendImage, a frameImage(from a JavaCameraView), and a maskImage. I need to blend the blendImage and the frameImage using a lighten blend mode with an alpha calculated from maskImage applied. To do this, I premultiply I calculate the value of the darkened frameImagePixel and do comparisons with that. However...

```
for (int i = 0; i < blendImage.rows; i++) {
    uchar *blendImagePixel = blendImage.ptr(i);
    uchar *frameImagePixel = frameImage.ptr(i);
    uchar *maskImagePixel = maskImage.ptr(i);
    int channelsToBlend = min(3, blendImage.channels()); //if it exists, never blend alpha channel
    for (int j = 0; j != blendImage.cols * blendImage.channels(); j += blendImage.channels()) {
        uchar adjustedMaskImagePixel = saturate_cast<uchar>( (maskImagePixel[j] * maskContrast) + maskBrightness);
        for (int c = 0; c < channelsToBlend; c++) {

            float alpha = (float) map(adjustedMaskImagePixel, 0, 255, 0, 1); //if black, alpha = 0
            float beta  = (float) 1.0 - alpha;

            switch (blendMode) {
                case LIGHTEN: {

                    /* THIS WORKS AND I DON'T KNOW WHY */
                    frameImagePixel[j + c]  = (uchar) (frameImagePixel[j + c] * alpha);
                    if (blendImagePixel[j + c] > frameImagePixel[j + c])
                        frameImagePixel[j + c] = blendImagePixel[j + c];

                     /* THIS DOESN'T WORK AND I DON'T KNOW WHY
                    uchar darkenedFrameImagePixel = (uchar) (frameImagePixel[j + c] * alpha);
                    if (blendImagePixel[j + c] > darkenedFrameImagePixel )
                        frameImagePixel[j + c] = blendImagePixel[j + c];
                    */

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I calculate the value of the darkened frameImagePixel and store it in the frameImagePixel itself, the final image is perfect. 
However, when I calculate the value of the darkened frameImagePixel but store it in a uchar and do a comparison with that uchar variable, the result is noisy with damaged colors - basically a glitchy mess.
I don't understand. These two phrasings seem equivalent. Why does one work perfectly and the other break?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operations aren't seemingly equivalent. In the first case

```
frameImagePixel[j + c] = (uchar) (frameImagePixel[j + c] * alpha);
```

changes `frameImagePixel` independent of

```
if (blendImagePixel[j + c] > frameImagePixel[j + c])
```

Every pixel is multiplied by alpha. In the second case if

```
blendImagePixel[j + c] < darkenedFrameImagePixel
```

nothing happens. Not all pixels are multiplied by alpha. That's a big difference.

Example:

First case

```
frameImagePixel[j + c] = 10
alpha = 0.5
blendImagePixel[j + c] = 0
=> frameImagePixel[j + c] == 5
=> blendImagePixel[j + c] > frameImagePixel[j + c] == false
```

Second case

```
frameImagePixel[j + c] = 10
alpha = 0.5
blendImagePixel[j + c] = 0
=> darkenedFrameImagePixel == 5
=> blendImagePixel[j + c] > frameImagePixel[j + c] == false
=> frameImagePixel[j + c] == 10
```